# Floor in Haskell and Ints

Tags: haskell, int, floor

When I use floor in Haskell i.e. floor 1.7 I assumed it would give me 1 and it's type would be an Int but I keep getting an error message as if this is not the case?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `floor 1.7` by itself will not cause any error. You should show a code sample that is complete enough to reproduce the error.

Comment: Flagged as unclear, since it's been four years without the OP filling in the missing details.

Answer (score 7):

Works fine for me:

```
ghci > floor 1.7
1
ghci > :t floor 
floor :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b
```

You can force it to be of `Int` type by explicitly mentioning the type:

```
ghci > floor 1.7 :: Int
1
```

Or if you want `Integer` then,

```
ghci > floor 1.7 :: Integer
1
```

Comment: I get: "No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from the literal `0.7' Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Int).

Comment: All I am asking for is the return type of floor 1.7?

Comment: @James: `floor` is polymorphic. Its signature is `(Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b`. In your case, `1.7` has type `Double`, so that's `a`, and `floor 1.7` has type `(Integral b) => b`. If you also want `floor 1.7` to have a concrete type (such as `Int` or `Integer`), you do what @Sibi writes in his answer.

Comment: I would also add that it is a bit annoying that you won't show the/some code that gives you the error in question.

Comment: @James If you want to treat the result as a `Double`, you need to convert it to `Double` first by calling `fromInteger` on it. So the thing you want to do is `fromInteger (floor 1.7)`. This is because `floor` returns an `Int` but a lot of the mathsy things you do expect `Double`s.

Comment: @James Where did the `0.7` come from?